# What’s the shortcut for “Edit All in Scope” in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

In Xcode, there's a feature to edit variables or codes within a scope:

[image: Scope editing]

In my IDE, this feature only works when I move my mouse over a variable. Most of the time, I don’t get this feature. Since it’s fairly useful, I’d like to use it more often.

Is there a keyboard shortcut for this? (Please don’t tell me to use “Find and replace”.)

Comment: Please post comment when you are downvoting, so that I can improve.

Comment: I downvoted you because the info was super super easy to find. Even one click on the help menu and typing "edit all" would have given you a big fat blue arrow pointing directly at the menu entry and keyboard shortcut. Obviously, you didn't even bother to look in the most obvious places.

Comment: Thanks for the question. Having this stuff easy to reach here is helpful.

Comment: I retracted my down vote. That was wrong. This site is about having easily found help for others, and apparently this was a real concern for people.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

**Menu:** Editor -> Edit All In Scope (also shows key binding)

**Keyboard Shortcut:** <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>

If you want you can change this key binding on Preferences -> Key Bindings -> search for "Edit all in scope".

**EDIT:** In Xcode 9, you may want to instead use the fabulous new "Rename…" functionality, which works across classes, also renames files and comments, and gives you a neat preview. As of beta 2, this does not have a default keyboard shortcut, but you can easily give it one.

Comment: FYI if you use Evernote and it is open, this shortcut is hijacked and has to be turned off even if Xcode is in focus.

Comment: How do you give it a shortcut? Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work if Xcode is saying error for that very name.

Comment: If you have Evernote, make sure you go to `Evernote -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts` and override `Search in Evernote`  with a different shortcut.

Comment: WTF, Xcode is such a crappy IDE, it even does not provide a default shortcut?!

Answer (score 23):

Press `Cmd-Ctrl-E` to edit all in scope

Comment: This doesn't change the name of one that is also defined in the storyboard.

Answer (score 12):

For xCode 9 there is not default hotkey for Refactor > Rename

[image]

But you can setup it:

for instance,  `Ctrl + Shift + R`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After xCode 8.3 you may also need to,

- check
  `Highlight instances of selected symbol` *option* in `Preferences` - `Text Editing` pane

[image]